# Can RadScheduler display dates on y axis?

Tags: axis, telerik-scheduler

Hey,
This seems like it should be possible with this control.
Can I set up the telerik RadScheduler to display resources across the top on the x axis and dates on the y axis?
thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question is No, this is not possible. Got the answer directly from telerik.